# Inverter elementos de um vetor em C

Tags: c, array, c++, matriz

Boa tarde!
Pessoal alguém sabe como faço para inverter elementos de um vetor, por exemplo, digito 12345 e o programa retorna 54321
Fiz assim, mas não deu certo!
[![  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVkRM.png][1]][1]

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int vetOriginal[5], vetInvert[5];
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
    {
        printf("Digite um número!\n");
        scanf("%d", &vetOriginal[i]);
    }

    for(j = 0; j >= 4; j-- )
    {
        vetInvert[i] = vetOriginal[j];
        printf("O vetor invertido é |\n %d", vetInvert[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Basta trocar for(i = 0; j <= 4; i++, j--) por for(j = 0; j >= 4; j--)

Comment: Bem-vindo. Evite postar imagem do código, prefira postar o próprio código na pergunta. Fica mais fácil pra simular, copiar e colar, etc. Aproveite e dê uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Para inverter faça: for (i=0; i<5; i++) vetInvert[i] = vetOriginal[4-i];

Comment: @André Esse `for` que vc sugeriu nunca será executado, pois se `j` começa em zero, a condição `j >= 4` é falsa e por isso nunca entra no loop: https://ideone.com/xCBbTP

Answer (score 0):

Você está sempre colocando na primeira posição o que você quer inverter, sem variar o i apenas o j

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5
int main(){
    int vetOriginal[N], vetInvert[N];
    int i = 0, j = 0; // recomendo sempre iniciar com 0

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("Digite um número!\n");
        scanf("%d", &vetOriginal[i]);
    }
    i = 0;
    for(j = N-1; j >= 0; j-- ){
        vetInvert[i] = vetOriginal[j];
        i++;
    }
    printf("O vetor invertido é: ");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%d", vetInvert[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Caso você queira, pode colocar o segundo for para funcionar dentro do primeiro, assim economiza 1 for

Answer (score 0):

Você pode controlar os elementos a serem invertidos com apenas um índice:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5
int main() {
    int vetOriginal[N], vetInvert[N];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Digite um número!\n");
        scanf("%d", &vetOriginal[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        vetInvert[i] = vetOriginal[N-i-1];
        printf("O vetor invertido é |\n %d", vetInvert[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Caso queira utilizar duas variáveis como índices faça o controle dos dois índices no loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int vetOriginal[5], vetInvert[5];
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Digite um número!\n");
        scanf("%d", &vetOriginal[i]);
    }

    for(i=0, j = 4; i<5 && j >= 0; i++, j-- ) {
        vetInvert[i] = vetOriginal[j];
        printf("O vetor invertido é |\n %d", vetInvert[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note que na sua solução o valor contido na variável i após o loop inicial é 5 e você movimenta para esta mesma posição, fora da área declarada para o vetor que vai dos índices 0 a 4, todos os elementos do vetor original.

Answer (score 0):

No caso você teria que inverter desta forma:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
      int vetor[5],vetorInv[5],i,n=5;
      printf("Digite 5 valores para um vetor: \n");
      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        scanf("%d",vetor[i]);
      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("vetor[%d] = %d \n",i,vetor[i]);
      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      {
        vetorInv[i]=vetor[n-1];
        n--;
      }
      printf("\n\n**Vetor Invertido**\n");
      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("vetor[%d] = %d \n",i,vetorInv[i]);
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Consegui, deu certinho!
muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
#define LC_CTYPE 2

char* setlocale(int, const char*);
int printf(const char*, ...);
int scanf(const char*, ...);

int _cdecl main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "PtB"); // Para escrever em português do Brasil
    printf("Digite cinco números (ex. 1 12 23 34 45): ");

    int x;
    int vetor_original[5] = {0};

    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        if (!scanf("%i", &vetor_original[x])) {
            printf("Erro.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int y;
    int vetor_invertido[5] = {0};

    for (x = 4, y = 0; x > (-1); x--, y++) {
        vetor_invertido[y] = vetor_original[x];
        printf("%i\n", vetor_invertido[y]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ou seja, vi[0] = vo[4], ..., vi[4] = vo[0].

Se o usuário não separar os números por espaço ou *Enter*, receberá mensagem de erro. O programa foi testado e funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    
    int x[5];
    int i;
    
    printf("\nDigite 5 numeros: \n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    
    scanf("%d", &x[i]); 
        
    }
    //Eu coloquei 4 porque em um vetor de 5 posições, a primeira posição é 0. 
    for(i=4;i>=0;i--){
        printf("%d", x[i]);
    }   
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

int main(){

```
int i, v[5];
//Aqui eu já estou inserindo elementos no vetor de forma invertida;
for(i=4;i>=0;i--){ 
    scanf("%d",&v[i]); 
}
//E depois lendo de forma crescente normal
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("\n%d",v[i]);
}

//Aqui eu estou inserindo os elementos em um vetor corrente 
printf("\n------logica 2------\n");
for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
    scanf("%d",&v[i]);
}
// E depois invertendo a leitura do vetor
for(i=4;i>=0;i--){
    printf("\n%d",v[i]);
}

return 0;
```

}